# Is there a solution to the following error message in nextflow: Process 'MPILEUP' has already been used - -

Tags: nextflow

I am running a nextflow pipeline or NGS processes - indexing of ref genome, fastqc, multqc, alignment, sorting and mpileup. The pipeline was successful run until I added the MPILE process.
The command for running mpileup is

bcftools mpileup -O b -o raw.bam.bcf -f $genome indexed_genome output.sorted.bam

Since the processes for running mpileup are BWA_INDEX and SAMTOOLS_INDEX, I have included them only in the pipeline below - the others are excluded:

```
params.reads = "$projectDir/data/ggal/*_{R1,R2}.fq.gz"
params.genome = "$projectDir/data/ggal/Agy99.fasta"
params.multiqc = "$projectDir/multiqc"
params.outdir = "results"

process BWA_INDEX {

tag{"BWA_INDEX on ${genome}"}
publishDir("${params.outdir}/bwa_index", mode: 'copy')
input:
path genome
output:
tuple path( genome ), path( "*" ), emit: bwa_index
script:
"""
bwa index ${genome}
"""
}

process SAMTOOLS_INDEX {
tag{"SAMTOOLS_INDEX on ${sample_id}"}
publishDir("${params.outdir}/bam_align", mode: 'copy')
input:
tuple val( sample_id ), path( bam )
output:
tuple val( sample_id ), path( "${sample_id}.aligned.sorted.bam.bai" ), emit: indexed_bam
script:
"""
samtools index "${sample_id}.aligned.sorted.bam"
"""
}
process MPILEUP {
tag {"MILEUP on ${sample_id}"}
publishDir ("${params.outdir}/bam_align", mode: 'copy')
input:
tuple val (sample_id), path (bam) path (genome)
output:
tuple val (sample_id), path ("${sample_id}.align-stats.txt"), emit: align_stats
script:
"""
bcftools mpileup -O b -o "${sample_id}.raw_bcf -f $genome {sample_id}.aligned.sorted.bam
"""
}


workflow {
ref_ch = Channel.fromPath( params.genome, checkIfExists: true )
reads_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads, checkIfExists: true)
BWA_INDEX( ref_ch )
BWA_ALIGN( BWA_INDEX.out.bwa_index.combine(reads_ch) ) 
SAMTOOLS_SORT( BWA_ALIGN.out.aligned_bam )
SAMTOOLS_INDEX (SAMTOOLS_SORT.out.sorted_bam)
SAMTOOLS_STATS (SAMTOOLS_SORT.out.sorted_bam)
MPILEUP (BWA_INDEX.out.bwa_index, SAMTOOLS_INDEX.out.indexed_bam)
}

//  Workflow Event Handler
workflow.onComplete {
println ( workflow.success ? """
Pipeline execution summary
Completed at: ${workflow.complete}
Duration    : ${workflow.duration}
Success     : ${workflow.success}
workDir     : ${workflow.workDir}
exit status : ${workflow.exitStatus}
""" : """
Failed: ${workflow.errorReport}
exit status : ${workflow.exitStatus}
"""
)
}

// The end


Process 'MPILEUP' has already been used - - if you need to reuse the same component, include it         with a different  name or include it in a different workflow context


Please, I have tried several times looking at the code (the nextflow code block) and the workflow execution block but haven't been able to identify the source of the problems. Thanks.

I tried linking the process SAMTOOLS_INDEX into a separate channels, such as below: 


samtools_index_ch = SAMTOOLS_INDEX (SAMTOOLS_SORT.out.sorted_bam)

And then combining it with BWA_INDEX process and passing them into MPILEUP process:


MPILEUP( BWA_INDEX.out.bwa_index.combine(samtools_index_ch)).


However, the same error message was displayed.
```